# mysql command line to vertical output

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'd like to get the result of a mysql query with a vertical output.
My problem when using --vertical (or G) is the starred lines.

```
    $mysql -N -e 'select filed1, field2 from db.tlb\G'
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
    value1_field1
    value1_field2
    *************************** 2. row ***************************
    value2_field1
    value2_field2
    ...
```

Is there an option I didn't find to get rid of the lines ***[...] x. row [...]*** ?

At the moment, I'm using a **egrep -v '^\*.*\*$'**, but I'm sure a better solution exists.

Comment: I think your method may be the best one - I don't believe there is an option to remove the row lines.  Other possibilities which are even more complex would be to select your columns as a tokenized concatenation then pipe into `sed` to convert the tokens to line breaks.  If what you have is working for you, I'd say stick with it.

Comment: +1 to yourself and from me :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a *good* solution, but if explicitly using `egrep` is annoying, you could define a shell function to launch `mysql` with the desired *pager*. Assuming you're using a *bash* (or compatible):

```
# define a shell function to launch mysql with the required _pager_
sh$ mysql() { `which mysql` $* --pager="egrep -v '^\*.*\*$'" ; }

[ ... ]

# launch mysql "as usual" (in reality, this is the shell function that is invoked)
sh$ mysql -u user -p -h mysql-host mydb
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 67
Server version: 5.1.49-3 (Debian)

-- Use mysql normally -- but the "egrep pager" will remove the "star lines"
mysql> select * from T\G
col1: w
col2: x
col3: 0.4
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As I said before, this is not a perfect solution since `egrep` will blindly remove from output any "star line" -- not only the one from an *ego* (`\G`) command.

Answer (score 0):

try this (but I can not imagine why you need such an output)

```
mysql -N -B -e 'select * from db' mysql | tr "\t" "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Option

would be to change the MySQL pager like so:

**test.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some Basic Configuration
db="homestead"
dbuser="homestead"
dbhost="127.0.0.1"
# Executes the MySQL command using the basic configuration
# This also sets the MySql Pager to less -Sin to enable
# it also removes all lines starting with "*"
mysql -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p --pager="grep -Ev '(^\*.*$)|(^$)' | less -Sin" $db
```

**Usage**

Firstly Edit the Config variables:

```
$ nano ./test.sh
```

Secondly Run the script

```
$ bash ./test.sh
```

### Second Option

Change the pager after you're already in the MySQL CLI

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 somedatabase
enter password:
mysql> pager grep -Ev '(^\*.*$)|(^$)' | less -Sin
```